# Count pair words for all combinations

Tags: mongodb, count, match

I have a database something like that in MongoDB:

```
{ "_id" : "piramidales", "LiciList" : [ "318081", "318157" ] }
{ "_id" : "pyramidalis", "LiciList" : [ "318081", "318157" ] }
{
        "_id" : "toneis",
        "LiciList" : [
                "318077",
                "318151",
                "318288",
                "318360",
                "318666"
        ]
```

I want to count pair words for all combinations!

How can I get the relationship of LiciList item? Like this:

```
{item1:'piramidales',item2:'pyramidalis',count:2},
{item1:'piramidales',item2:'toneis',count:0},
{item1:'pyramidalis',item2:'toneis',count:0}
```

Comment: AND if i wanted only object who has a intersect count > 0

{item1:'piramidales',item2:'pyramidalis',count:2}

Answer (score 1):

You can try following aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            item1: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
            item2: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$item1" },
    { $unwind: "$item2" },
    { 
        $project: { 
            _id: 0,
            item1: "$item1._id", 
            item2: "$item2._id",
            count: { $size: { $setIntersection: [ "$item1.LiciList", "$item2.LiciList" ] } }
        } 
    },
    {
        $redact: {
            $cond: {
               if: { $and: [{ $gt: [ "$item2", "$item1" ] }, { $gt: [ "$count", 0 ] } ] },
               then: "$$KEEP",
               else: "$$PRUNE"
            }
       }
    }
],
{ allowDiskUse: true })
```

Basically you have to generate the documents having pairs (item1, item2) and that's why we have to group everything into one document with two fields and then unwind twice. To count matching elements we can use [$setIntersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/). Then we have to filter out the duplicates using [$redact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/). Simply comparing strings using $gt will eliminate pairs like (`toneis`, `toneis`) or (`toneis`, `pyramidalis`) keeping (`pyramidalis`, `toneis`).

Comment: I tried and get a following message: rrmsg" : "Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.",
 "code" : 16945,
 "codeName" : "Location16945"

What do you suggest? I have a 32000 _id

Comment: Try to add this option, I've modified my answer

Comment: How to remove a count :0

Comment: @GabrielSartori check modified answer - simply extended $redact condition